# SignatureValue calculation for XML-DSIG

Tags: hash, xml-dsig

I am trying to write a method that returns a signature of an XML element for XMLDSIG using NET framework components (*RSACryptoServiceProvider*) in C++/CLI. Could please someone explain this excerpt from XMLDSIG specs ( http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmldsig-core-20020212/ ) in simpler words, for I am have very little programming and maths background and therefore have trouble undrestanding this - Or provide an excerpt form a real code as an example where this is implemented?

> The SignatureValue content for an RSA signature is the base64 [MIME]
>   encoding of the octet string computed as per RFC 2437 [PKCS1, section
>   8.1.1: Signature generation for the RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 signature scheme]. As specified in the EMSA-PKCS1-V1_5-ENCODE function RFC 2437
>   [PKCS1, section 9.2.1], the value input to the signature function MUST
>   contain a pre-pended algorithm object identifier for the hash
>   function, but the availability of an ASN.1 parser and recognition of
>   OIDs is not required of a signature verifier. The PKCS#1 v1.5
>   representation appears as:    CRYPT (PAD (ASN.1 (OID, DIGEST (data))))
>   Note that the padded ASN.1 will be of the following form:    01 | FF*
>   | 00 | prefix | hash where "|" is concatenation, "01", "FF", and "00"
>   are fixed octets of the corresponding hexadecimal value, "hash" is the
>   SHA1 digest of the data, and "prefix" is the ASN.1 BER SHA1 algorithm
>   designator prefix required in PKCS1 [RFC 2437], that is,    hex 30 21
>   30 09 06 05 2B 0E 03 02 1A 05 00 04 14 This prefix is included to make
>   it easier to use standard cryptographic libraries. The FF octet MUST
>   be repeated the maximum number of times such that the value of the
>   quantity being CRYPTed is one octet shorter than the RSA modulus.

In other words, if I am have the **hash** value for a certain XML element (not encoded in base64, is that right?), what do I do with it before sending it to the **SignHash** (in *RSACryptoServiceProvider*) function?
I know it's in the text, but I have troubles understanding it.
I don't understand "CRYPT (PAD (ASN.1 (OID, DIGEST (data))))" at all, although I understand parts of it... I don't understand the way to get the OID and then ASN and how to pad it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to explain the components, and see if this gets you any closer:

- DIGEST(data) is the hash-value you already computed
- OID is a globally unique identifier representing the hash-algorithm used. For SHA1 this is 1.3.14.3.2.26
- ANS.1 means ANS.1-encoding of the OID and the hash-value as an ASN.1-sequence. This means the hex-values listed in the reference, followed by the actual hash.
- PAD means concatenating 01 FF* 01 with the ASN.1-encoded prefix and the hash to get the desired length (FF* means repeat FF an appropriate number of times, the RFC gives details)
- CRYPT is the RSA-encryption-function

However, I believe the [signHash](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.signhash%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-function does all of this for you, you just provide the OID and the hash-value.

Comment: Thanks. It seems like both RSACryptoServiceProvider.SignHash() AND RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter.CreateSignature() create signature in PKCS1 v1.5